# What tools can I use to measure Active Directory response time to queries?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, performance

Windows Server 2008 / Active Directory

Is there a way to measure the response time for queries going to AD? I have an application that checks to see if a user exists in AD and lately, this seems to be taking awhile (30-40 seconds). I'd like to know if the delay is on the AD server side or with the application itself.

Would `csvde` be the best way of doing this? Or is there a special tool available for measuring AD query performance?  I'm open to using third-party utilities if that would provide a more complete picture of what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

How about

`Measure-Command {get-aduser -filter * -properties *|select $_.givenname,$_.sn,$_.mail, $_.mailnickname}`

or something similar (depending on what attributes etc your app queries)?

Answer (score 2):

If you suspect something on the AD side, there is new functionality that provides detailed performance in the event logs:

**Hotfix adds performance data to Active Directory event log in Windows Server 2012/2008 R2 SP1**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2800945

This article introduces a hotfix that adds performance data to the Active Directory event log on a Windows Server 2012-based or Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (SP1)-based domain controller. After you install this hotfix, the domain controller enables additional filters to log the following performance data:

```
Field   Description
callTime
    Call time (in milliseconds)
entriesReturned
    Entries returned
entriesVisited
    Entries visited
filter
    Used filter
index
    Used indexes
pagesReferenced
    Pages referenced
pagesRead
    Pages read from disk
pagesPreread
    Pages pre-read from disk
pagesDirtied
    Clean pages modified
pagesRedirtied
    Dirty pages modified
```

Note: You can collect the performance data in the Active Directory event log to analyze the cause of a failure.

After you install this hotfix, the work that is required to troubleshoot issues that involve unexpectedly high CPU usage in the Lsass.exe process and long logon times is reduced. More specifically, the additional filters that are described in the "Symptoms" section are added to event ID 1644. When the Field Engineering logging level is set, event ID 1644 can also be logged when a Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) query exceeds a time threshold. The time threshold is configured in a DWORD value named Search Time Threshold (milliseconds) that is located under the following registry subkey:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NTDS\Parameters
```

When the Field Engineering logging level is enabled and the Search Time Threshold (milliseconds) registry entry is not used or set to 0, the default value of the time threshold is 300,000 milliseconds.

For more information about how to use event 1644 to troubleshoot LDAP query performance issue, go to the following Microsoft website:

**Creating More Efficient Microsoft Active Directory-Enabled Applications**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms808539.aspx

Answer (score 1):

What's funny is there used to be (maybe there still is from a quick Google search) a tool on Novell called "Elapsed Time" that did something very similar to this.

It looks like **ADFind from JoeWare** can give you elapsed time though...that might help.

http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/adfind/usage.htm

Looks like these two switches will do the trick:

> **-elapsed**      Display elapsed time in seconds that the search
> occupied.
>
> **-selapsed**     Display elapsed time in seconds for various
> points of execution.